# select and delete record in transaction sql

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions

I am using oracle as my database server. I have a simple sql table which stores codes for each member. I want to remove code from the table but also get the value of it.

```
SQL> describe member_code_store;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 MEMBER                    NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 CODE                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
```

So I want to run below queries in a transaction

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String query =
        "SELECT code FROM member_code_store where coupon=? AND rownum=1";
Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, String.valueOf(3));
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
rs.next();
String code = rs.getString(1);
```

delete the code now

```
String query =
        "delete from member_code_store where coupon =? AND code=?;";
Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, String.valueOf(3));
pstmt.setString(2, code);
rs = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Problem with the above code is that multiple workers removing the codes will get the same code. How do I enclose the transaction so that I just lock the record instead of locking the whole table.

Or should I use procedures or packages which are more efficient?

Comment: Oracle and sql-server use different locking mechanisms.  for oracle, see this - https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:927629362932

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you should use row lock. The example I show includes the nowait option, which wil return an error if you try to select the row that is lock and your code will have to handle that.

```
select code, rowid 
from member_code_store
where coupon=? AND rownum=1
for update of code nowait
```

Save the rowid so that you have a variable to supply to the delete statement

```
delete from member_code_store
where rowid = :row_id
```